# How can I install 32bit(x86/i386/i686) ubuntu 16.04 on Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

As far as I know, in google cloud platform, google only supports 64bit system basically.

But I need to use 32 bit linux.

I've followed this link(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YlcR6ZLebTM), but gcp vm instances hangs when booting from created image.

Is there anyways?

Answer (score 2):

There are specific requirements that need to be met when building a custom OS in Google Cloud Platform. All of them are listed in the [Building Custom Operating Systems](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/building-custom-os) official docs page. Notice that there is one security setting in kernel build options for 32 bit kernel:

> `CONFIG_X86_PAE=y`
>
> Set this option for a 32 bit kernel, as PAE is
>   required for NX support. This also enables larger swapspace support
>   for non-overcommit purposes.

You can also [import boot disk image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/import-existing-image) to Google Compute Engine.